# Propagate a dict in a Listbox of tkinter

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter, listbox

I list a dictionary {‘337’:’Anderson’,’47’:‘Stuttgart’ ...} in a tkinter Listbox widget. That work for me. With curselection() I can also pick up a value like ‘Anderson’ with a double click.

My function looks like:

```
def select_xml(event):
    widget = event.widget
    selection = widget.curselection()
    value = widget.get(selection[0])
    print (value)
```

This print e.g. Anderson.

Question: Is the key of my dict lost, or how can I retrieve the key of my selected value. I couldn’t find any information about dict and Listbox.

Comment: create dict `{'Anderson': '337', 'Stuttgart':'47' ...}` and then you can find value `337` using `Anderson` as key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you create `Listbox` but you can convert your list to

```
{'Anderson': '337', 'Stuttgart':'47' ...}
```

and then get `337` using `Anderson` as key.

```
data = {'337':'Anderson', '47':'Stuttgart'}

data2 = {val:key for key,val in data.items()}

print(data2)

print(data2['Anderson'])
```

If you have the same name many times in dict then converting may remove some values and then better filter original dict using list/dict comprehension

```
keys = [key for key,val in data.items() if val == 'Anderson']

print(keys)
```

but if you have the same name many times then you get many keys and you will don't know which one to choose. It would be better to create list with (key,values) and then use `selection[0]` as index in this list

```
data = {'337':'Anderson', '47':'Stuttgart'}

data2 = [(key, val) for key,val in data.items()]

selection = [0]

print( data2[ selection[0] ] )
```

---

Minimal working code

```
import tkinter as tk
        
# --- functions ---

def on_click(event):
    widget = event.widget
    sel = widget.curselection()
    val = widget.get(sel[0])
    
    print('dict2:', dict2[val])
    print('list2:', list2[sel[0]])
    print('---')

# --- main ---

data = {'337': 'Anderson', '47': 'Stuttgart'}

dict2 = {val:key for key, val in data.items()}
list2 = list(data.items())

root = tk.Tk()

listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
listbox.pack()

listbox.insert('end', *data.values())
listbox.bind('<Double-Button-1>', on_click)
             
root.mainloop()
```

Result:

```
dict2: 47
list2: ('47', 'Stuttgart')
---
dict2: 337
list2: ('337', 'Anderson')
---
```

Comment: Thank. That’s exactly what I searched for.